# ObservableBoolean databinding does not update view when set

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I'm trying to get databinding to work, but so far with no success.

My MainActivity.java contains this:

```
public ActivityMainBinding binding;
private Button createPartyButton;
public final ObservableBoolean partyIsCreated = new ObservableBoolean(false);

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

 createPartyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_party_button);
 createPartyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    partyIsCreated.set(!partyIsCreated.get());
  }
 });
}
```

My activity_main.xml is this:

```
<layout>
  <data>
    <variable
      name="main"
      type="com.example.MainActivity"/>
  </data>
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/my_nickname_text"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:enabled="@{main.partyIsCreated ? true : false}"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/create_party_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/create_party_button_text"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

My build.gradle in android section contains this:

```
 dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Rest of build setup is this:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
gradle:2.3.0
```

I can see that the databinding got autogenerated. But nothing happens in the view. What have I missed to get databinding to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not setting the variable:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    binding.setMain(this);
}
```

But that isn't the only problem. First, you're using `findViewById()`, which is totally unnecessary with data binding. You can access the view with the ID `create_party_button` by referencing the public field in the binding: `binding.createPartyButton`.

What's more is that you don't need to access it at all. I don't necessarily advise using the Activity itself as a view model or controller as you're doing, but if you do:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    public final ObservableBoolean partyIsCreated = new ObservableBoolean(false);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        binding.setMain(this);
    }

    public void partyClicked() {
        partyIsCreated.set(!partyIsCreated.get());
    }
}
```

And you set the click handler in the layout itself:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/create_party_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/create_party_button_text"
        android:onClick="@{() -> main.partyClicked()}/>
```